# How to combine multiple requests response nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I have an array of data and need to fetch data for each item and combine them.

```
// This is inside a Nextjs async API route

const data = ['item1','item2','item3']

let result = []

data.forEach(async (item)=>{
const res = await fetch(`https://websitename.com/${item}`)
console.log(res)  //gives a valid data
result = [...result,...res]
}

console.log(result)  //gives an empty array
```

Here, it returns an empty array even though for each item data is being fetched. How to make such requests?

Comment: Because you are executing the `Async` function inside the `loop`.

Comment: You cannot use forEach with async

Answer (score 0):

The answer you get is in json format.
You must convert it before you can use it

```
const res = await fetch(`https://websitename.com/${item}`    
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, then it's probably more of an async thin ,  JS is not fill the array before you call it

Answer (score 0):

Because you are executing the `async` function inside the `loop` where it only returns `promise` for each execution. In this case, You can use `Promise.all()`

```js
const data = ['item1','item2','item3']

let requests = data.map(item => {
    return fetch(`https://websitename.com/${item}`);
};

Promise.all(requests).then((responses) => {

    // Reason of using flat is, You will get array of responses like [[res1], [res2], [res3]]
    // If you want to merge those together, You can use flat()
    const results = responses.flat();

    // do whatever you want with results

});
```

[Read about using Async/Await in Array methods](https://medium.com/sliit-foss/js-async-await-in-array-methods-9142a35c6d6f)

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = ['item1','item2','item3']

let result = []

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    const res = await fetch(`https://websitename.com/${data[i]}`)
    console.log(res)  //gives a valid data
    result = [...result,...res]
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.